# How to remove multiple elements from a list>

Tags: python-3.x

Question :

Days is a list with 30 elements. Write a short snippet of code that will remove the 5th, 12th, and 23rd elements from days.

The only way i can think of answering this question is by using splicing. 
Will this work x = x[0:5] + x[6:12] + x[13:23] +x[24:31]??? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove list elements by their indexes:

```
x = [e for i, e in enumerate(x) if i not in [5, 12, 23]]
```

Comment: @user2971015: look at both code examples: what code is easier to understand (what it does), maintain and extend. What if you want to delete 10th element instead of 12th -- what changes do you need to perform in both cases? what is less error-prone? What if you found out that the input indexes are `1`-based instead of `0`-based: how would you change both examples? (note: [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) has `start` parameter) What if indexes are given as a list in a variable? It should answer your question.